# What is the correct way to get all databases from MongoDB through Java Driver

Tags: mongodb

I want to use MongDB Java driver to connect to Mongo instance. I am able to create a MongoClient instance and now I want to get all the database names. I see that there is a method `getDatabaseNames` which meet my requirement but it is deprecated. There is another method `getDatabase(databasename)` but I have to know the database name before calling this method. Is there a way for me to get all database names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadocs for deprecated method has the name of the replacement method.

http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDatabaseNames--

> Replaced with MongoClient.listDatabaseNames()